# Confused by the use of $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) in separate stage from published Artifact

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

### Problem:

`$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` is empty, despite being able to view the published Artifacts in the Azure DevOps Pipeline UI, which causes the pipeline to fail.

### What I'm trying to do:

1. Build microservice (e.g., `/api`).
2. Run unit tests.
3. If unit tests are passing, publish the build as an Artifact.
4. Dockerize the build Artifact using `buildContext`.

This is based on advice [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/425232/clarifying-the-steps-in-a-ci-cd-but-namely-if-if-unit-testing-should-be-done-bu), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67012723/building-application-for-unit-testing-and-then-adding-to-docker-image), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57590336/how-to-copy-azure-pipeline-artifacts-to-a-docker-image-which-is-microsoft-dotnet/59450867#59450867).

### Publish Stage Config

My config for publishing after unit tests have passed is the following:

```
- publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ parameters.pathName }} 
  artifact: ${{ parameters.pathName }}
  condition: succeeded()
```

- `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` should be `/home/vsts/work/1/s/` from what I gather.
- `${{ parameters.pathName }}` is just `api`.
- I can see correct artifacts are generated in the Azure DevOps Pipelines UI.

### Docker `buildAndPush` Stage Config

My config for grabbing the artifact and using it in a Docker `buildAndPush` config is the following:

```
- task: Docker@2
  condition: contains(variables['servicesChanged'], '${{ parameters.serviceName }}')
  displayName: Build and Push ${{ parameters.pathName }} Docker image
  inputs:
    command: buildAndPush
    repository: $(imageRepository)-${{ parameters.pathName }}
    dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)/${{ parameters.pathName }}/Dockerfile
    buildContext: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
    tags: |
      ${{ parameters.tag }}-${{ parameters.tagVersion }}
```

- From what I gather, `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` should be `/home/vsts/work/1/a/`.
- ***However, it is empty and this stage fails.***
- `$(dockerfilePath)` is equal to `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`.

### `Dockerfile` Config

Informational, but this is what the `Dockerfile` contains:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", ":5000", "--log-level", "info", "config.wsgi:application", "-t", "150"]
```

### Project Structure

```
/project-root
  /admin
    package.json
    Dockerfile
  /api
    requirements.txt
    Dockerfile
  /client
    package.json
    Dockerfile
```

### What I've Tried

```
dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)/${{ parameters.pathName }}/Dockerfile
buildContext: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)


Step 5/17 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 277ce44b61cf
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
##[error]The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

```
dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)/${{ parameters.pathName }}/Dockerfile
buildContext: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ parameters.pathName }}


unable to prepare context: path "/home/vsts/work/1/a/api" not found
##[error]unable to prepare context: path "/home/vsts/work/1/a/api" not found
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

```
dockerfile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ parameters.pathName }}/Dockerfile
buildContext: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)


##[error]Unhandled: No Dockerfile matching  /home/vsts/work/1/a/api/Dockerfile  was found.
```

```
dockerfile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Dockerfile
buildContext: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

##[error]Unhandled: No Dockerfile matching  /home/vsts/work/1/a/Dockerfile  was found.
```

### What Has Worked

```
dockerfile: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ parameters.pathName }}/Dockerfile
buildContext: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ parameters.pathName }}
```

But doing this seems to negate the need to `publish` as an Artifact. Maybe this is the "correct" way, I don't know. It seems like it is doing what I want to accomplish by `COPY` what was built for unit testing into the Docker image instead of using a different version.

I'm pretty sure this isn't what I'm after since it looks like it is just cloning the repo again to `/home/vsts/work/1/a/` at the beginning of this stage.

### Question(s)

- Why is `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` empty?
- Is it a deprecated env var?
- Is using what I have in "What Has Worked" supposed to be the correct way of how to handle this? ***(I don't think that it is)***.
- So how should I be persisting the tested build between the unit testing stage and the Docker stage so I can use the exact build from the unit testing stage?

Comment: Some newer tasks use the newer Pipeline.Workspace variable. The docker task doesn't specify a default working directory at all. I'm not entirely sure what world er it ends up in.

Comment: Did you add a dependsOn in your second stage to ensure the artifacts do get downloaded?

Comment: Have you tried the [PublishPipelineArtifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use:

```
- publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ parameters.pathName }} 
  artifact: ${{ parameters.pathName }}
  condition: succeeded()
```

behind the scene it uses `Publish Pipeline Artifact task` which by default downloads

> downloads files to $(Pipeline.Workspace). This is the default and recommended path for all types of artifacts.

So please try

```
buildContext: $(Pipeline.Workspace)
```

or

```
buildContext: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{ parameters.pathName }}
```

However, it makes sense when you have multi stage pipeline (which I'm not sure as you didn't publish the whole pipeline). Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#migrate-from-build-artifacts)

> For build artifacts, it's common to copy files to $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) and then use the Publish Build Artifacts task to publish this folder. With the Publish Pipeline Artifact task, you can just publish directly from the path containing the files.

So there is no need to move files to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` before publishing them. Thus for a newer and recommended task this folder can be empty all the time.